# Is std::nth_element guaranteed to partition in the presence of ties?

Tags: c++

I understand that (1) [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) orders elements of an array spanning [first, last) such that !(*j > *i) holds for any i in [first, nth) and j in [nth, last).

Is it also guaranteed that (2) for any k where (*k == *nth), then !(*j > *i) holds for any i in [first, k) and j in [k, last)?

Comment: No. 1) Since it's not mentioned in specification, no matter what anyone says, you can't rely on this. 2) The algorithm is a plus-minus standard quicksort-based partitioning, and it doesn't guarantee things you are asking about.

Comment: @dyukha I know en.cppreference.com is really good but where would I look up the official standard just to be sure?

Comment: Well, I personally blindly trust cppreference. I believe this is the standard: iso.org/standard/68564.html. Here there is its early draft: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf (maybe there is a better link, i don't know).

Comment: The default ordering is `<`, not `>`.

Comment: There's no `==`. The operation you are looking for is `equiv`, which is defined as `!(*j < *i) && !(*i < *j)` (or `!comp(j, i) && !comp(i, j)`)

Comment: @molbdnilo notice the ! (it wrapped the line)

Comment: @Caleth That has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @THK Exactly. The text you misquoted says `!(*j < *i)`. (No element “to the right” of `nth`, including `nth` itself, is ordered before any element “to the left” of it.)

Comment: @molbdnilo You are right! I reversed the comparison in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (1) `std::nth_element` orders elements of an array spanning **[first, last)** such that **!(*j > *i)** holds for any **i** in **[first, nth)** and **j** in **[nth, last)**.

That would be true if you were sorting in **descending** order, like passing `std::greater` as comparison function. The page you linked uses the expression **!(*j < *i)**, which is similar to what the Standard says (n4659 draft, § 28.7.2, *[alg.nth.element]*)

> ```
> template
>   void nth_element(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator nth,
>                    RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp);
> ```
>
> [...] *Effects:* After `nth_element` the element in the position pointed to by `nth` is the element that would be in that position if the whole range were sorted, unless `nth == last`. Also for every iterator `i` in the range `[first, nth)` and every iterator `j` in the range `[nth, last)` it holds that: `!(*j < *i)` or `comp(*j, *i) == false`.

Newer drafts have different wording, but basically the same condition.

---

Your second point assumes that the algorithm somehow "packs" the values equal to the nth

> Is it also guaranteed that (2) for any k where (*k == *nth), then !(*j > *i) holds for any i in [first, k) and j in [k, last)?

A particular implementation may end up with this kind of partition (see e.g. this [case](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sZ8gbiyzmlTAOMfp)), but that is **not** guaranteed by the Standard. If you need it, you have to post process the result, like [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4ojI2JRjUmP8jfEB).

Comment: Oh Stack Overflow, where people spend more time addressing a typo than the question... But this is the best answer (second part). Thanks for the pointer to stable_partition. I was using partition to post-process after nth_element and was basically wondering if it was necessary. As everyone has pointed out, it is.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Consider `std::vector<int> vec = {5, 5, 5, 10, 1};`

After calling `std::nth_element(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 2, vec.end());`, a valid ordering is

```
{ 5, 1, 5, 10, 5 }
```

Because all of `{ 10, 5 }` are not less than each of `{ 5, 1 }`.

Note however the first `5` is not less than `1`, which follows it; and `10` is not less than the last `5`, which succeeds it.

Comment: Isn't the call supposed to be `std::nth_element(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 2, vec.end())`? It seems the end and nth element are swapped with respect to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element

Comment: @gc5 oops, yes.